# Existing Facebook API for online shop

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, fbconnect

Is there an existing App or API that can grab all my product info on my FB shop page?
I am trying to add existing product of my FB shop on the website I am developing now which online Buy and sell site.

Could somebody tell me if there is already existing?

Comment: There is no API for that yet.